# FirebaseError: Firebase: Hostname match not found

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, firebase-authentication, vercel

When i try to send otp from localhost, it is send successfully but when I try to send otp from vercel deployed url it gives me errro FirebaseError: Firebase: Hostname match not found.
And also I can not find the authorised domain in firebase to add domain.

I want the otp to be send from the vercel deployed (https://hepyy.vercel.app/Verificatio) url also.
ANd if it is done by adding authorised domain to firebase please tell, how to add authoried domain?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same authentication issue, and I have solved them by following these steps:

1. Go to your firebase and open the authentication section.
2. Click on the `Settings` tab to switch to it.
3. Click on Authorized Domains section.
4. Click on Add Domain.
5. Then enter your domain without and slashes or protocols. This is the domain in the URL that you have mentioned `hepyy.vercel.app`
6. Lastly click on Add Domain

Then when you go to the website it should work.

I hope that I have helped you :)